# Get data to component in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-redux

I have `Dashboard` component below

```
        import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import WidgetService from '../../../Services/QueenBase/Widget/WidgetService';

    function Dashboard() {
        const [widgetData, setwidgetData] = useState([]);
        const [widgetItem, setWidgetItem] = useState({});
        useEffect(()=>{
            getWidgetData();
        },[]);

        const getWidgetData = async () => {
                var wData=await WidgetService.get().getWidgetData();
                setwidgetData(wData);
        }

        const FetchWidgetData = async(widget) => {
            var res = await WidgetService.get().getData(widget);
            setWidgetItem({data:res});
            setIsGetData(true)
            return res
        }

        const GetData = (props) => {
            if(!isGetData){
            FetchWidgetData(props.data.widget);
            }
            return (
                <div>{widgetItem.data}</div>
            )
        }

        };
        const displayWidgetBoxes = () => {
            const sequenceArray = []
            widgetData && widgetData.forEach(element => {
                    sequenceArray.push(element.sequence)
            })

            return sequenceArray.map((element,i) => {
                if (element) {
                    return (<GetData data={element} />)
                }
            })
        }

            return (
            <div className='row wcont'>
                {displayWidgetBoxes()}
            </div>  
            );
    }

    Dashboard.propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.object
    };


    export default Dashboard;
```

In `GetData` I need to call API `FetchWidgetData` and display that data to `div` inside `GetData`;

But Everytime The data is displayed with the last data in the loop

Suppose `FetchWidgetData` has [3,5,8], then `displayWidgetBoxes` should return

```
 <div>3</div>
 <div>5</div>
 <div>8</div>
```

But the data is returning as

```
 <div>8</div>
 <div>8</div>
 <div>8</div>
```

Comment: You only have a single `widgetItem`, and you're overwriting it multiple times. Whichever API call finishes last, that's the one that provides the data for it. You need an array of widgetItems.

Comment: Also don't declare components within other components.

Comment: @ChrisG So do I need to write different components?